# Error when building AngularJSToDo hybrid app in Visual Studio

Tags: installation, targets, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio 2013 - CTP2,and other development tools are properly set up.
Now  I get some errors when trying to build for Android, iPhone, and for Windows Phone.
  error 1: Cannot find module 'qs'
  error 2: “"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "AngularJSToDo" --language "zh-CN"” exited with code 8。   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets

please help me with this problem.

Comment: Could you please post Output messages from Visual Studio Output window?

Comment: Following is all output information:1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : 由于未为 TypeScript 编译器给定要编译的文件，因此该编译器将跳过编译。
1>  F:\exercise\2014\HybirdProgramm\HelloWorldMVA\HelloWorldMVA>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.26 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\bhhi0ak0.n12\packages\vs-mda

Comment: 1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;

Comment: 1>EXEC : error : Cannot find module 'qs'
1>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
1>      at require (module.js:380:17)
1>      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\index.js:21:10)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

Comment: 1>      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
1>      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
1>      at require (module.js:380:17)

Answer (score 1):

It seems something went wrong while installing Cordova and other dependencies. [q](https://www.npmjs.org/package/q) module is a library for promise.

Run following npm commands from command prompt,

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open cmd
3. `npm install -g [path to vs-mda example C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda]`
4. `npm install -g [path to vs-mda-targets example C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets]`
5. Open project and build