# Command failed with exit code ENOENT in visual studio 2013

Tags: android, node.js, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013

### Hi i am getting this error while trying to build my application in visual studio 2013 community   version

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>Build started 12/1/2014 4:12:42 PM.
1>TrackJsChanges:
1>  GeneratedJavascript=scripts\index.js;scripts\index.js.map;scripts\platformOverrides.js;scripts\platformOverrides.js.map
1>InstallMDATargets:
1>  D:\VBWORKSPACE\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\DOFNNIMZ.R4T\packages\vs-mda
1>MDAVSCLI : error : C:\Users\sourav.phukon\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\create: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:11.87
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

```
Please suggest how can i resolved this issue.....
```

Comment: This fix my problem. Hope you find it useful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757260/error-when-building-angularjstodo-hybrid-app-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution ....
just go to Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and it works fine..

when i tried for first time i got another different error during bulid as
 MDAVSCLI : error : Cannot find module 'q' error
if you got this error open cmd prompt and try this cmd
npm install ripple -g

Try to clean cordava again and create a new project now its works fine for me...